# Método POST no funciona con UPDATE

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Estoy intentando que se puedan editar unas entradas mediante un formulario y este es el código:

**Formulario:**

```
<form name="nota_editar">
    <input type="hidden" name="noeid" value="<?=$mostrar_no['notas_id']?>" />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input class="form-control" name="noeasunto" value="<?=$mostrar_no['notas_asunto']?>" disabled/>
    </div><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="noeagente" value="<?=$_SESSION['placa']?>" />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="noetexto" rows="8"><?=$mostrar_no['notas_texto']?></textarea>
    </div><br>
    <div align="right">
        <button type="button" class="btn bg-secondary shadow-sm rounded-0 text-light" onclick="editarNota();">Editar nota</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

**Función con AJAX:**

```
function editarNota() {

  noeid = document.nota_editar.noeid.value;
  noeagente = document.nota_editar.noeagente.value;
  noetexto = document.nota_editar.noetexto.value;

  ajax = objetoAjax();

  ajax.open("POST", "query_post.php", true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
      actualizarNotas();
    }
  }

    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send("control=7&noeid="+noeid+"&noeagente="+noeagente+"&noetexto="+noetexto);
}
```

---

**Código PHP:**

```
if($control == 7) {
    $id = $_POST['noeid'];
    $agente = $_POST['noeagente'];
    $texto = nl2br($_POST["noetexto"]);
    $sql_eno = "UPDATE apol.notas SET notas_agente = $agente, notas_texto = $texto WHERE notas_id = $id";
    mysqli_query($con_apol, $sql_eno);
}
```

He usado para otras partes el mismo código pero con el método GET y no hay problema.
Necesito que se envien los campos del formulario y no se si había otra manera.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Hola claro te dejo un ejemplo parecido. Tendrias que asignar ID a los input

```
 var form_data = new FormData();

        form_data.append('noeasunto', $("#noeasunto").val());
        form_data.append('noeagente', $("#noeagente").val());
        form_data.append('noetexto', $("#noetexto").val());

        $.ajax({
            url: URL (Aqui va la url donde apunta el archivo php)
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (respuesta) {
                var datos = JSON.parse(respuesta);
                console.log(datos);

                if (datos['error']) {
                     $('#error_message').html(datos['error']);
                    
                    
                } else {
                    alert(datos['message']);
                  
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Lo estoy intentando implementar pero no lo entiendo muy bien. Le he puesto id a cada input y he puesto el archivo php, pero no se si en el evento onclick del botón tendría que poner FormData();. Lo he puesto así y no hace nada.

Comment: a tu boton solo colocale un id="button_enviar"; 

Update_datos(); esta es la función;  

onClick="Update_datos();"